# organise javascript code based on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am relatively new to javascript development.  At the moment I have a single javascript file with lots of little misc bits of code that get called in different part of the website.  For example I have an event handler for some google maps stuff that is only called on 1 single page, I have some validation stuff for my contact page etc etc.  My question, is how best to organise this code - given that each page only requires very little code but its different and specific per page?

Oh, I am using jquery if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6):

If there is nothing shared by each page from your js file and only a part of it is used by each page, the good way will be to separate each of those js code snippets for each page. This will simply improve **page loading** a little depending on the size of your javascript file.